# Remove caps lock indicator from password field

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, osx-lion

Is there a way to get rid of OSX / web-kit caps lock indicator on input type password?
http://jsfiddle.net/EaTf4/

```
<input type="password" class="foo"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

The caps lock indicator is browser-specific (webkit?)

You could use a default textfield with a little bit of jQuery on keyup event, replace the text with • bullets, and keep the real value in a variable. Here is a old fiddle with an option to show the password while typing.

```
$('#clearpasstextfield').change(function(){
   // store value, replace field with bullets
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GDmac/DdmuZ/